# git push が反映されない

Tags: git

Vagrant上のローカルリポジトリから，リモートのリポジトリに $ git push をしたときに，$ git log 上ではコミットメッセージが表示されるのに，リモートのファイルに変更が反映されません．なぜでしょうか？

Comment: リモートはどうやって確認しているのでしょうか？　例えば、pushしたブランチとpullしているブランチが違うと、リモートに反映されていないように見えます。

Comment: pullもしてみましたが，同じリモートでpullできました．両方ともmasterブランチで行っています．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず: vagrant はあんまり関係ないと思います。一般化して、 CUI 上の unix 環境において、以下の方法が有効かと思います。

---

今、問題になっているのは、「git push (したと思っていて、手元で git log を実行したところ commit メッセージがちゃんと表示されているにもかかわらず) リモートのブランチに反映されていない」ことだと理解しました。ひとまず、

```
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs より引用)

をローカルで実行してみてはいかがでしょうか。上記を実行すると、わかり易い情報の `git log --all` が取得できます。`gitk` や Source Tree などの GUI の代わりに、それなりになってくれます。そこで、多分ですけど、 `origin/ブランチ名` (正確には、 `リモート名/ブランチ名`、以降「リモート追跡ブランチ」) みたいなやつがいて、それが変更されていなければ push できていません。

上記の方法で調べてもやはりたしかに git push 前後でリモート追跡ブランチが変更されていない、ということであれば、おそらく git push した際に何かしらのメッセージが出てるかと思います。それを元に検索するなどすれば原因はわかるかと思います。